# Redirecting to external url with params using zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

I want to redirect users to a external payment gate with some parameters using
zend.is there any standard way of doing it ?

really appreciate any advice and suggestions.

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the built in PHP function of [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build the parameters, then feed that to the `gotoUrlAndExit()` function of Zend Framework.

```
$url = "https://external.gateway.com/";
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

$query = http_build_query($data);

$this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrlAndExit($url . '?' . $query);
```

Comment: thanks guys awesome..special thanks to nvoyageur for example..u r a real time saver..

Comment: @sha, if you like my answer, please "accept" it and give it an upvote. This will build your reputation score.

Answer (score 4):

In ZF there is [Redirector](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector) action helper. It has methods called `gotoUrl()` and `gotoUrlAndExit()` that can be used to go to external urls. Maybe this helper will be suited for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->_redirect($url);
```

Just put it in your action